# Best way to change a value of a property. It's within an object of an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to switch the value of `selected` from whatever it currently is (true or false) to the opposite when a user clicks on a checkbox. My `toggleCheck` function is supposed to return all data with the altered select value. Here's the data structure. It's an object with arrays that have objects.

```json
{
    "ModuleName": [{
            "module": "string",
            "selected": false,
            "name": "title",
            "points": [{
                    "category": "category1",
                    "description": "desc1",
                    "provided": "provided1"
                },
                {
                    "category": "category1",
                    "description": "desc",
                    "provided": "something"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "module": "string",
            "selected": false,
            "name": "title_one",
            "points": [{
                    "category": "category1",
                    "description": "desc1",
                    "provided": "provided1"
                },
                {
                    "category": "category1",
                    "description": "desc",
                    "provided": "something"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [...],
    [...]
}
```

My closest attempt but it's the wrong format

```js
function toggleCheck(checkedValue, valuesArr) {
    return {
        value: Object.entries(valuesArr).map(([key, values], i) =>
            values.map((x) => {
                return {
                    ...x,
                    selected:
                        x.name === checkedValue.name ? !x.selected : x.selected,
                };
            })
        ),
    };
}
```

probably cause I used a map it wrapped it in an array

```json
[
   [ 
      {},
      {},
      {}
   ],
   [...],
   [...]
]
```

^^^ What I got

```json
{
    "Name": [  {},
               {},
               {}
            ],
    "Name": [...],
    "Name": [...]
}
```

^^^ What I need

Comment: "So I'm trying to switch the value of selected from whatever it is to the opposite onClick of a checkbox." Could you reword this? My brain can't parse what it means for some reason.

Comment: You can convert back to an object with `Object.fromEntries()`

Comment: @Swiffy yeah sorry about that. I edited it. Is that better?

Comment: And Oh I didn't think about using that @Barmar

Comment: the `^^^ What I need` can't be exist in JS object. Only the last assignment of the        `name`  property will be taken into account, all the previous ones are only old values of this property

Comment: @MisterJojo Oh yeah, that's what I need I only need to change the value of selected to the opposite. But still, everything else must be returned.

Comment: this is impossible, there can only be the last value. the others no longer exist

Comment: I'm like so determined since you told me it's impossible for what I'm asking... I'll update you guys if I figure it out :)

Comment: @MisterJojo Figured it out... so NOT impossible. If you see ways I can improve my current answer please lmk!

Comment: my advice: if you want to have answers be more precise in your questions

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleCheck(checkedValue, valuesArr) {

    //Step 0: Change the value in the data
    let checked = Object.entries(valuesArr).map(([key, values], i) =>
        values.map((x) => {
            return {
                ...x,
                selected:
                    x.name === checkedValue.name ? !x.selected : x.selected,
            };
        })
    );

    //Step 1: Group the modules into like arrays
    let grouped = checked .flat().reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        if (!i || r[r.length - 1][0].module !== a.module) {
            return r.concat([[a]]);
        }
        r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

    //Step 2: Assign the new object properties as the arrays. 
    //The key being the module name.
    let newObj = {};
    grouped.map((x, i) => {
        newObj[x[0].module] = x;
    });

    return {value: newObj};
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your question you wrote:

```
{
    "Name": [  {},
               {},
               {}
            ],
    "Name": [...],
    "Name": [...]
}
```

*^^^ What I need*

---

this can't be exist in JS object. Only the last assignment of the name property will be taken into account, all the previous ones are only old values of this property

codding :

```
const data = 
  { name:'aaa'
  , name:'bbb'
  , name:'ccc' 
  }
```

is the same as coding

```
const data = {}
data.name = 'aaa'
data.name = 'bbb'
data.name = 'ccc'
```

proof:

```js
const data = 
  { name:'aaa'
  , name:'bbb'
  , name:'ccc' 
  }

console.log( data )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: Ahh I see what you're talking about. But yeah `name` is different for each key mister, those are just placeholders...misunderstanding bud all good